# jQuery tabs width issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs, width

I'm having an issue with the width of my tabs when using jquery tabs in dreamweaver.

I want 4 tabs to span the full width of the content box, so 100% total, 25% per tab, right? The only problem is when i choose 25%, my 4th tab moves down a row. The highest % width i can have before the tab moves down is 24.7%, but this leaves a tiny hap at the end of the content box.

This would suggest that there is some padding somewhere that i've not accounted for, but i can't seem to find any.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

update: code on the tabs

```
.ui-tabs{
position: relative;
padding-top: 0em;
padding-right: 0em;
padding-left: 0em;
padding-bottom: 0em;
zoom: 1;
border-radius: 10px;
margin-top: 40px;
/* [disabled]width: 100%; */
}.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav{
margin: 0;
border-top-right-radius: 15px;
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
position: absolute;
top: -32px;
left: -1px;
width: 100%;
}.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li{
list-style: none;
float: left;
position: relative;
top: 0;
margin-top: 1px;
margin-left: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
border-bottom: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
width: 25%;
}.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a{
float: left;
padding-top: .5em;
padding-right: 1em;
padding-left: 1em;
padding-bottom: .5em;
text-decoration: none;
}.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active{
margin-bottom: -1px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
}.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a,.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-disabled a,.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-loading a{
cursor: text;
}.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a,.ui-tabs-collapsible .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a{
cursor: pointer;
width: 0%;
}.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel{
display: block;
border-width: 0;
padding-top: 1em;
padding-right: 1.4em;
padding-left: 1.4em;
padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Do you have code or Fiddle?

Comment: if u r using <div style=' float: left'> or something like this and  u have to change the 25% to 24% 
if there is no other mistake it will work :D

Comment: Padding, margins, or a border is mot likely to blame. Can't really help you without any code.

Comment: Alireza - div style float left on which css property?

Comment: Don't use Dreamweaver.  I recommend adding a CSS reset to the top of your stylesheet to get rid of any unwanted default padding and margins

Comment: style='folat:left' if u use this on 3 div they will be shown on a row